# Parse Data From Excel Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

In Excel 2013 in one cell (but on different lines) there is 
Store Name
Address
City, State, Zip

I want to parse it out so that I have Name, Address, City, State, Zip all in one cell.  This is what my data looks like in cell A1

```
Bell & Jean Industries
6413 Oakhaven Ridge Road
Foxfire, FL  55121
```

Now I tried to get crafty and input in cell E1 `=A1` which puts the data on one line, **BUT** it does not add a space between Company, Address and City so my concatenation will not work (also, if I right click the cell and uncheck wrap text it is the same result).

I normally will use this syntax to strip out the needed data, but since there is no space, my syntax does not work.  How can I strip out Address, City, State, Zip info when the data is presented in this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," ")
```

You need to replace the new line character with a space

Comment: Excellent, so easy and simple!